# 400 bad request while calling web service

Tags: jquery, jpa

I'm getting a bad request from server while calling a web service using jquery ajax post.
my code looks like this :-

```
$("#dailyEntryUpdate").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = $("#dailyEntryForm").serialize();
    var id = billingObject[localStorage.index].billingId;

    var parameters = values+"&Id=" + encodeURIComponent(id); 

    console.log("  values are "+ parameters);
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8080/TIMS/rest/UpdateEntry/update",
          type: "POST",
          data: parameters,
          success: function(){
              alert("Record updated successfully");
          },
          error:function(){
              alert("failure");
          }   
        });
});
```

And the server side looks like this

```
    @XmlRootElement
@Path("/UpdateEntry")
public class UpdateEntryService{

    @POST
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void updateBillingList(
            @FormParam("truckNo") String truckNo,
            @FormParam("Source") String source,
            @FormParam("Destination") String destination,
            @FormParam("BookingDate") String bookingDate,
            @FormParam("UnloadingDate") String unloadingDate,
            @FormParam("Weight") int weight,
            @FormParam("Freight") float freight,
            @FormParam("Advance") float advance,
            @FormParam("Balance") float balance,
            @FormParam("Commision") float commision,
            @FormParam("Hamali") float hamali,
            @FormParam("DelieveryCharge") float delieveryCharge,
            @FormParam("Remarks") String remarks,
            @FormParam("Detention") float detention,
            @FormParam("Id") String id) {

              EntityManager em = DaoHelper.getInstance().getEntityManager();
              try{
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                Billing bill = em.find(Billing.class, id);
                bill.setAdvance(advance);
                bill.setBalance(balance);
                bill.setCommision(commision);
                bill.setDelieveryCharge(delieveryCharge);
                bill.setDetention(detention);
                bill.setFreight(freight);
                bill.setHamali(hamali);

                DailyEntry entry = bill.getEntry();
                entry.setBookingDate(bookingDate);
                entry.setDestination(destination);
                entry.setRemarks(remarks);
                entry.setSource(source);
                entry.setTruckId(truckNo);
                entry.setUnloadingDate(unloadingDate);
                entry.setWeight(weight);

                em.getTransaction().commit();
              } finally {
                em.close();
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the parameters as GET in the AJAX POST method.

You must send the parameters as:

```
data: { key: value}
```

format.

Comment: no i am sending the parameters as POST in ajax request. . data is serialized using jquery.serialize()

Comment: yes the method is POST, but you constructed the parameters for the GET request style `var parameters = values+"&Id=" + encodeURIComponent(id);` , you need to modify as above for the POST.

Comment: var values = $("#dailyEntryForm").serializeArray(); values.push({name:"Id", value:id})                                 data: values;         Still getting the same error. .

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you used [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to construct the POST parameters

```
var parameters = $("#dailyEntryForm").serializeArray();
var id = billingObject[localStorage.index].billingId;

parameters.push({name: "Id", value: id});
```

jQuery will convert and encode all values appropriately when you pass the `parameters` to the `data` property of the ajax call.

Comment: yes, i've tried that, but i'm still getting the same error. .

Comment: Not enough information to debug further: What is the server error? What format is the server expecting to receive the post data? Are all the required fields being passed? Do all the HTML inputs have a name attribute to allow serialization?

Comment: OK,it seems that worked but now the error is bit different, the server is not able to get any parameters passed as json, it's showing null values for every parameter, but the actual data is passed in POST. .

Comment: my server is expecting data in form encoded. . and i'm trying to read that using @formparam but i'm not able to read that value. .

Comment: Your previous comment is confusing: you said the data was in the POST body but the data passed as JSON was empty. If your server-side method is expecting form-urlencoded data, make sure the name of each HTML input matches the parameter name exactly. Not enough information to continue debugging. Can you provide a test URL?